# How to fuse two Application Branches into one for iOS App store?

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, in-app-purchase

We have two Apps live on the Appstore. One for free, and one full featured version which is offered to buy. The free app has a In-App-Store so the user may update to the full featured version.

Actually I am thinking about stoping development of the full featured App (which is identical
to the free one at code level). We don't want to blame our customers. It would be nice to give them a redemption code for the free app to unlock all features. All features which will be unlocked this way are bound to the redemption code. All customers who did In-App purchases are "registered" by Apple, so the purchase will be remembered for all devices. Finally all In-App customers would have an advantage over the Pro-Version customers, which is not acceptable for us.

Is it possible to have one (hidden) free In-App purchase, which the user could "buy" if the redemption code is working? Maybe a better question is: What is the best practice for putting two similar Apps together without bugging the customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, I'm afraid. There is no good solution as far as I am aware (I still have a paid and a "lite" version for this reason).

You could raise a bug report with Apple (http://bugreporter.apple.com) but there's no saying if of when they'll ever make a change.

Comment: It's a pitty that some interesting things are actually not so easy to do. Deployment can be a very annoying process. Not only for the company and developers, but sometimes for the customers, too. I hope in future the "roadmap" of Apple will be more "visible", so we can adopt early to those things, avoiding deployment traps.

Answer (score 1):

How about this idea:

1. Add a URL scheme to your lite app which, when invoked, enables the full featured version.
2. In your next update for the paid app add a button to "Enable all features in the lite version" that invokes that URL scheme (`UIApplication`'s `openURL:`). This will open the lite app which will then enable all features.

One problem: if somebody else figures out what that URL scheme is, he could write a simple little app that just uses that URL scheme to enable the features in your lite app. Which means that person could get all the features without ever buying your paid app.

To prevent this I would implement this URL scheme in such a way that it only works when called with a secret parameter, maybe the hash of the device's MAC address and a salt. (Not sure if this is the best way, but that would be my first idea)

Comment: Very good idea. But checking if this is an "legal" operation is still not easy. But I see now, that deployment is something we do have to do by ourselves. The idea with URL scene is nice.